# winphone let code wait for 2 seconds DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, timer

I m doing image processing for Win Phone, using visual studio 2010.
In order to let a a picture displayed for 2 seconds (like slide show), the following class is called

```
namespace photoBar
{
    public class WaitTwoSeconds
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        public bool timeUp = false;

        // This is the method to run when the timer is raised. 
        private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                                EventArgs myEventArgs)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timeUp = true;
        }

        public WaitTwoSeconds()
        {
            /* Adds the event and the event handler for the method that will 
               process the timer event to the timer. */
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

            // Sets the timer interval to 2 seconds.
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2); // one second
            timer.Start();

            //// Runs the timer, and raises the event. 
            while (timeUp== false)
            {
                // Processes all the events in the queue.
                Application.DoEvents();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

It is called in this way:

```
        WaitTwoSeconds waitTimer = new WaitTwoSeconds();
        while (!waitTimer.timeUp)
        {
        }
```

Because the `Application.DoEvents();` is claimed as an error: 'System.Windows.Application' does not contain a definition for 'DoEvents' . So I deleted that code block

```
        while (timeUp== false)
        {
            // Processes all the events in the queue.
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

After compile and run the program, it shows resume ...
How could I correct this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be done much more easier using Reactive Extensions (reference Microsoft.Phone.Reactive):

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Subscribe(_=>{
    //code to be executed after two seconds
});
```

Beware that the code will not be executed on the UI thread so you may need to use the Dispatcher.

Comment: +1 this is actually a better route to go in the long run than mine.  Don't fear the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Embrace multithreading.

```
public class WaitTwoSeconds
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    Action _onComplete;

    // This is the method to run when the timer is raised. 
    private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                            EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        _onComplete();
    }

    public WaitTwoSeconds(Action onComplete)
    {
        _onComplete = onComplete;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2); // one second
        timer.Start();

    }
}
```

And in your code

```
private WaitTwoSeconds waitTimer;
private void SomeButtonHandlerOrSomething(
    object sender, ButtonClickedEventArgsLol e)
{    
    waitTimer = new WaitTwoSeconds(AfterTwoSeconds);
}

private void AfterTwoSeconds()
{
    // do whatever
}
```

This design isn't that good, but it should give you a clear understanding of how multithreading works.  If you aren't *doing something*, then **don't block**.